# Is the character Rigsy a nod to Banksy?

Tags: doctor-who, inspiration

[Rigsy](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Rigsy) was a one-off Doctor Who character who became a two-off when he appeared in both Series 8 "Flatline" and Series 9 "Face the Raven". Originally, he was a graffiti artist doing community service.

That name seems similar to an (anonymous yet famous) real-life graffiti artist, [Banksy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banksy). Is there any solid evidence (e.g. direct quotes from Moffat or the writers of those episodes, similarities in graffiti style, anything else I've missed) that **Rigsy was based on or inspired by Banksy?**

Comment: I mean, for all we know, Rigsy _is_ Banksy.

Comment: The BBC's in-house rag certainly thinks so; "*Flatline evidently hasn’t had much money chucked at it in terms of settings, costumes and big-name guest stars. Instead, it exudes refreshing urban grit. As valid a depiction of unappreciated art as Vincent and the Doctor, it creates a hero out of Bristolian graffiti artist Rigsy – in a sly homage to Banksy (also Bristol-born). And it’s enriched by a wealth of ideas that feel original but have actually been at the core of Doctor Who since its inception.*" - https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/sci-fi/doctor-who-guide/flatline/

Comment: It's worthy of note that the episode is set in Banksy's home town of Bristol.

Comment: Hmm. Moffat created a character in Sherlock with a strong Banksy-esque graffiti style; https://bakerstreet.fandom.com/wiki/Raz

Comment: Nothing in his Official Profile; https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/profiles/4SSHRP9Bm03sLFk3jMJY4Yn/rigsy

Answer (score -3):

The identity of real-life Banksy is still unconfirmed, even though many believe they know who he is. All that can be said about Banksy with any certainty is that he is a celebrated artist working under what is believed to be a pseudonym. Given that the character of Rigsy is different from Banksy in every known respect (their identity is not a secret, nor are they successful or celebrated as an artist), it would seem that there was no intention that viewers should associate him with the real-life artist. The very slight similarity in their names might be a nod towards the real-life artist, but that is a superficial connection.

Although some appear to be pointing towards third-party articles that draw a connection based on their name and chosen art-form alone, these do not necessarily reflect the intentions of the writer.

### Differences between the two:

- The shooting script for *Face the Raven* reveals that Rigsy's full name is Christopher Riggins. Deriving a nickname from a surname in this way is quite common, especially in British English - 'Banksy' would be a common nickname for someone surnamed 'Banks', just as 'Jonesy' could be a nickname for someone surnamed 'Jones'. Banksy might not be as successful at concealing his identity if this monicker were based on his real name, so the fact that one is an artist operating under a pseudonym and the other is just going by a derivation of his real name is a major difference, given that the name is one of only 2 superficial similarities.
- Banksy's art is sought-after and considered to be valuable, whereas the character of Rigsy is considered to be a vandal - the episode sees him carrying out community service as a result of his graffiti. Again, this is a major difference in one of only two superficial similarities.

Additionally, the fact that the Thirteenth Doctor later acknowledged Banksy in the episode *Rosa* makes him a real person in the Doctor Who universe, so there is no need for a fictional character to occupy his space.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. The question isn't whether Rigsy *is* Banksy, but rather whether the character was *based on or inspired by* Banksy.

Comment: @Valorum I feel I've answered that question in my first paragraph, with evidence. The second paragraph is just an additional point, partly in response to some comments on the question, but also because it negates the need for there to be a character filling the role of Banksy in the Who universe.

Comment: "*real-life Banksy is a pseudonym*. Indeed, but it's supposedly short for his original pseudonym, Robin Banks, so it's a relatively small jump from Banks=Banksy to Riggs=Rigsy

Comment: @Valorum I've updated my answer slightly to solidify my point. Shortening names like that is very, very common. If it was intended as a nod to the artist, it was extremely superficial. There is little or no similarity between the two as people. A shortening of a pseudonym is still a pseudonym. Shortening a real name makes no effort to hide one's real name.

Comment: Given that there is no public information on who Banksy actually is in real life, any comment on where his pseudonym originated from is pure speculation.

Comment: @PeterM - Well, no. The Times newspaper reported his identity as well as the genesis of his pseudonym; https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/signed-banksy-album-artworks-go-up-forsale-xsj23zz2j. Whether you choose to believe them or not is rather down to you.

Comment: @Valorum I (sort of) stand corrected.  I say sort of because I'm not signing up for a account the Times just to read a single article.  So I'm taking your word for it.

Comment: How are Banksy and Jonesy _shortenings_ of Banks and Jones?

Comment: @TonyK That's a little picky - the process of taking the first syllable of a surname and adding "y" or "sy" is what I what I was referring to. It could be a shortening, depending on the surname, but I agree it isn't in the examples which is why I said they were nicknames rather than shortenings. But to avoid any confusion for you, I've taken out the word "shortening".